# Problem with "Dimension without coordinates" in xarray

Tags: matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I am trying to figure out why I cannot have a complete plot of from a data array I regrided to another resolution.

The original data array looks like that:

```
>>> Orig_data
<xarray.DataArray 'VISdn' (lat: 192, lon: 288)>
dask.array<mean_agg-aggregate, shape=(192, 288), dtype=float32, chunksize=(192, 288), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -90.0 -89.06 -88.12 -87.17 ... 87.17 88.12 89.06 90.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 0.0 1.25 2.5 3.75 5.0 ... 355.0 356.2 357.5 358.8
```

While after using the libraries xESMF:

```
ds_out = xe.util.grid_2d(0.0, 360.0, 1.0, -90.0, 90.0, 1.0)
regrid_Orig_data = xe.Regridder(Orig_data, ds_out, 'bilinear', periodic=True)
Orig_new_reg = regrid_Orig_data(Orig_data)
```

I got that:

```
>>> Orig_new_reg 
<xarray.DataArray (y: 180, x: 360)>
dask.array<_regrid, shape=(180, 360), dtype=float32, chunksize=(180, 360), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
    lat      (y, x) float64 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 ... 89.5 89.5 89.5 89.5
    lon      (y, x) float64 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 ... 356.5 357.5 358.5 359.5
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Attributes:
    regrid_method:  bilinear
```

Then, I plot the new data (Orig_new_reg ) using Matplotlib and cartopy only shows my half of the data.
Is this due to the new data says it is "Dimensions without coordinates: y, x"?.
How I can solve that?

Thanks in advance